# iPhone : Browse documents

Tags: iphone, file, itunes, sandbox

I have searched a little about file browsing on iPhone and i'd like to confirm some of my conclusions :

- an App can't browse files outside its sandbox. Examples : no app can browse the files inside 'iBooks','voice Memos', 'Notes' ..etc. One exception however: the 'Photos' app sandbox is browsable through `UIImagePickerController`.
- browsing an app's directory from itunes is possible if File-Sharing is enabled (`UIFileSharingEnabled`).

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct. :) Easiest response ever!

Well, to clarify, the directory browsable in iTunes with UIFileSharingEnabled is specifically your app's ~/Documents directory. (You can make use of other directories with particular functionality, like ~/Library/Caches, which is ignored by iCloud backups and subject to deletion when the device is low on storage.)